# Creating OpenGL Shadows

Tags: opengl, shadow

Does anyone know a good place to learn how to implement shadows in openGL?  Or does anyone know how to do this?  I know it isn't built into openGL by default but I can't seem to find any good examples.  I've created a cube sitting on top of a plane in which I'm going to test this.  I've created the cube and plane using:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
```

to create a flat plane as well as a six sided cube that sits on that plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating shadows is an advanced technique (well, there are at least 3 methods applicable in your case). Before even attempting to do so, you need a firm grasp of OpenGL and it's concepts.

OpenGL is not a scene graph, it's a drawing API, so the idea is to combine drawing operations in a way, that you'll end up with what looks like correct shadows.

You may want to look up the topics:

- Shadow Buffers
- Stencil Volume Shadows
- Planar Projection Shadows

Each finds tons of Google results. Add OpenGL to the seach term and you'll get numerous tutorials for each.

Comment: Thanks this got me a good start.  Found a nice example that I was able to strip down to the simplest point and work from there.  Hopefully at some point I can find a place to host my striped down code example because while shadows are not simple most of the examples are more complex than they need to be.  I've got a simple cube rotating and casting a shadow on a wall.  Thanks again.